# Entity Framework adds a null empty row before the actually row, when adding test data (a reservation)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem that when adding a reservation, or my test data to the database (using Entity Framework), it created an empty null row in one of the tables.

I have 3 tables

- Reservation
- ContactPerson
- Rooms

There is a many to many relationship between `Reservation` and `Rooms`. There is a one to many between `ContactPerson` and `Reservation`.

I'm using the code-first approach.

**Reservation** class:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public Reservation()
    {
        Room = new List<Room>();
        ContactPerson = new ContactPerson();
    }

    public int ReservationID { get; set; }
    public string ReservationNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
    public int ContactPersonID { get; set; }

    public virtual ContactPerson ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Room> Room { get; set; }
}
```

**Room** class:

```
public class Room
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Occupied { get; set; }
    public bool Smoking { get; set; }
    public bool Minibar { get; set; }
    public int Beds { get; set; }
    public RoomTypeEnum? RoomType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

public enum RoomTypeEnum
{
    Single = 0, Double = 1, Family = 2, Suite = 3
}
```

**ContactPerson** class:

```
public class ContactPerson
{
    public int ContactPersonID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Nationality NationalityType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

public enum Nationality
{
    Denmark, Germany, England, France, Holland, Belgium, Norway, Sweden, Finland
}
```

My `DataContext` class:

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; }
    DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; }
    DbSet<ContactPerson> ContactPersons { get; }
    int SaveChanges();
    void MarkAsModified(Reservation item);
    void MarkRoomAsModified(Room item);
    void CreateReservation(Reservation item);
}

public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DataContext")
    {

    }

    // DbSet to bookings
    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContactPerson> ContactPersons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public void MarkAsModified(Reservation item)
    {
        Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void MarkRoomAsModified(Room item)
    {
        Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void CreateReservation(Reservation item)
    {
        Reservations.Add(item);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Room).WithMany(i => i.Reservations)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ReservationID")
            .MapRightKey("RoomID")
            .ToTable("RoomReservation"));
    }
}
```

I'm inserting test data with the `Configuration` class that is being generated when you use migrations.

**Configuration:**

```
protected override void Seed(WebApplication1.DAL.DataContext context)
{
        var reservations = new List<Reservation>
            {
                new Reservation{ReservationNumber = "123456789", CheckInDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01"), CheckOutDate = DateTime.Parse("2016.01.15"), ContactPersonID = 1
                }
            };

        reservations.ForEach(b => context.Reservations.AddOrUpdate(r => r.ReservationID, b));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var contactPersons = new List<ContactPerson>
            {
                new ContactPerson{Title = "Mr" ,FirstName = "Anders",LastName = "Christensen", Email = "AndersChristensen@gmail.com", NationalityType = Nationality.Denmark, PhoneNumber = "44216731" }
            };

        contactPersons.ForEach(b => context.ContactPersons.AddOrUpdate(c => c.ContactPersonID, b));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var rooms = new List<Room>
        {
            new Room {RoomNumber = "101", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = true, Smoking = false},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "102", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = true, Smoking = false},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "103", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = false},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "104", Beds = 2, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Double, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = true},
            new Room {RoomNumber = "105", Beds = 3, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Family, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = false},
        };

        rooms.ForEach(b => context.Rooms.AddOrUpdate(b));
        context.SaveChanges();

        AddOrUpdateReservation(context, "101", "123456789");
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    void AddOrUpdateReservation(DataContext context, string roomNumber, string reservationNumber)
    {
        var reservation = context.Reservations.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ReservationNumber == reservationNumber);
        var room = reservation.Room.SingleOrDefault(r => r.RoomNumber == roomNumber);
        if (room == null)
            reservation.Room.Add(context.Rooms.Single(i => i.RoomNumber == roomNumber));
    }
```

The `Reservation` table looks good, the `Rooms` table looks good, too, and the shared table `ReservationRoom` also looks good. The problem is the `ContactPerson` table, when I add a room or reservation, it will add an empty row before added the right contact person.

You see it in this screenshot:

[image]

Here you see the result just after running commands, `add-migration InitialCreate` and `update-database`.

This also happens when trying to add a reservation I have create in my application, when using the method:

```
public void CreateReservation(Reservation item)
{
    Reservations.Add(item);
}
```

The reservation table look like this:

[image]

Here you can see it points to the empty null row that has been created for some reason.

Hope someone can tell me what could be wrong here. I have used days trying to reconfigure the models and stuff, but none have seem to worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this kind of issue because your `Reservation` constructor implementation is incorrect :

```
public Reservation()
{
    Room = new List<Room>();
    ContactPerson = new ContactPerson();
}
```

Implemented like this, you automatically create a new `ContactPerson` for the reservation. Then when saving `Reservation` in your `Seed` method it will not use the one `ContactPerson` person you created in that `Seed` method.

Change your constructor to this :

```
public Reservation()
{
    Room = new List<Room>();
}
```

Then in your `Seed` method, because each `Reservation` must have a `ContactPerson` you should insert `ContactPerson` before creating attached `Reservation` like this :

```
protected override void Seed(WebApplication1.DAL.DataContext context)
{
    var contactPersons = new List<ContactPerson>
        {
            new ContactPerson{Title = "Mr" ,FirstName = "Anders",LastName = "Christensen", Email = "AndersChristensen@gmail.com", NationalityType = Nationality.Denmark, PhoneNumber = "44216731" }
        };

    contactPersons.ForEach(b => context.ContactPersons.AddOrUpdate(c => c.ContactPersonID, b));
    context.SaveChanges();

    var reservations = new List<Reservation>
        {
            new Reservation{ReservationNumber = "123456789", CheckInDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01"), CheckOutDate = DateTime.Parse("2016.01.15"), ContactPersonID = 1
            }
        };

    reservations.ForEach(b => context.Reservations.AddOrUpdate(r => r.ReservationID, b));
    context.SaveChanges();

    var rooms = new List<Room>
    {
        new Room {RoomNumber = "101", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = true, Smoking = false},
        new Room {RoomNumber = "102", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = true, Smoking = false},
        new Room {RoomNumber = "103", Beds = 1, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Single, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = false},
        new Room {RoomNumber = "104", Beds = 2, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Double, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = true},
        new Room {RoomNumber = "105", Beds = 3, RoomType = RoomTypeEnum.Family, Minibar = true, Occupied = false, Smoking = false},
    };

    rooms.ForEach(b => context.Rooms.AddOrUpdate(b));
    context.SaveChanges();

    AddOrUpdateReservation(context, "101", "123456789");
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I think also you can call `SaveChanges` once at the end of your method but for that to work you need to avoid using constant foreign key like you're doing.

Comment: Finally it works! hell ye. Have been trying in 2 days to find out what where causing this problem :D many many thanks to you sir, and good day.